# class-validator validate union type

Tags: typescript, class-validator

I have a [mongoose discriminator schema](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html), which mean the data will be different according to one of the attributes.

```js
class Feature {
  name: string
  option: ColorFeature|SizeFeature
}

class ColorFeature {
  kind: 'color'
  color: string
}

class SizeFeature {
  kind: 'size'
  size: number
}
```

What is the correct way to validate the `Feature` class so that it only accepts 2 different kinds?

Comment: have you ever figured it out? I have the same problem.

Comment: @DavideTalesco just added back my answer

Answer (score 20, accepted):

it can be achieved by using `validateNested()` together with [class-transformer discriminator](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#providing-more-than-one-type-option)

```js
class BaseFeature {
  kind: 'size' | 'color'
}

class ColorFeature extends BaseFeature {
  kind: 'color'
  color: string
}

class SizeFeature extends BaseFeature {
  kind: 'size'
  size: number
}


class Feature {
  name: string

  @ValidateNested()
  @Type(() => BaseFeature, {
    keepDiscriminatorProperty: true,
    discriminator: {
      property: 'kind',
      subTypes: [
        { value: SizeFeature, name: 'size' },
        { value: ColorFeature, name: 'color' },
      ],
    },
  })
  option: SizeFeature | ColorFeature;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

I spent a lot of time with this, and I finally found a cleaner way of doing it than the current answer.

Basically, the decorator `@Type` gives us some helper options if we want to use them, such us.. the object! So, you can return one type or the other conditionally, so the validation is done over one of the two types:

```js
class Feature {
  name: string

  @ValidateNested()
  @IsDefined()
  @Type(({ object }) => {
    if(object.option?.kind === 'color') return ColorFeature;
    else if(object.option?.kind === 'size') return SizeFeature;
    // Handle edge case where the previous ifs are not fullfiled
  })
  option: ColorFeature | SizeFeature
}
```

You can even use a `switch case` or some Record for cleanliness sake in case you have more types:

```js
  @ValidateNested()
  @IsDefined()
  @Type(({ object }) => {
    switch(object.option?.kind){
      case 'color':
        return ColorFeature;
      case 'size':
        return SizeFeature;
      case 'shape':
        return ShapeFeature;
      default:
        // Manage edge cases
    }
  })
  option: ColorFeature | SizeFeature | ShapeFeature
```

Then, you also have to use validation decorators in the extended classes, so that they are correctly validated.

Comment: ` Property 'object' does not exist on type 'TypeHelpOptions | undefined'.` Is it stil working? class-validator@^0.14.0